# Why do trigonometric functions work?

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

Sine is equivalent to the opposite side over the hypotenuse. It's formula (simplified) would be this:
$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} + \frac{x^9}{362880} - \cdots $$

However, I really want to know: why does this work? Why can *this* specific function be used on any right angle, and produce the opposite over the hypotenuse? The formula itself almost seems random. How does it relate to those sides?

Comment: If you work basing on the unit circle definition, it should be easy to see.

Comment: Take calculus, or perhaps just find and read a calculus book. That's a Taylor series, and understanding why that series exists and why the coefficients have those values is going to require a lot of calculus.

Comment: Note, that here, $sin(x)$ does not mean : x in degrees. Instead, $x$ is dimensionless and $360°$ corresponds to $2\pi$. So, $sin(90°)=sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. If you put $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the series, you will get $1$

Comment: @Peter Yes, I know that degrees won't work with it.

Comment: It takes quite a lot of work to actually prove that this formula is true; I doubt you could find a complete proof in any calculus book.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't doubt it. The only things you need are $\sin'=\cos$, $\cos'=-\sin$, $\sin0=0$, $\cos0=1$ and Taylor series. There should be a comprehensive enough calculus book that discusses all these facts.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: How do you prove that $\sin x$ is actually real-analytic (i.e., equal to its Taylor series)?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Good point. I thought this would be easy but come to think of it I'm not actually sure how that's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is an example of what is called a "Taylor series" which is based on the concept of derivatives. The correctness of the formula for the sine function is intimately connected to the differential connections between sine and cosine, namely, that $\sin' = \cos$ and $\cos'=-\sin$.

These two facts can be straightforwardly demonstrated using geometry, based on the usual definitions you know for sine and cosine. (If you know the angle addition formulae $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$ and $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$ you're already halfway there). Then all that's left is calculus and the theory of Taylor series.

Also, note that the formula might appear less random if you rewrite it as

$\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}$

Which in turn will appear less random once you realize the general Tayolr series is

$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$

So really the only thing left to show is that the repeated derivatives of sine are $0, 1, 0, -1$ repeating in a cycle.